# Camera and gallery crashes when hard key return/back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-keypad

The camera crashes when the hard key return button is pressed.[image] This affects both the gallery and taking photo on the camera in the app. I tried handling this by checking if the intent `action()` is not null. But it still crashes. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==0){
        if(data.getAction() != null){
        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        if(theImage !=null){
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
            }
        }

    }
    else if (requestCode == 1) {

        if(data.getAction() != null){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

       if(picturePath !=null){
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
       }
     }
    }
}
```

***update****

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            //getInfo is the Bundle
    if(data !=null || getInfo !=null){
        if(requestCode==0){
            if(data.getAction() != null){
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            if(theImage !=null || getInfo !=null || data!=null){
                iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `null` value checks inside `onActivityResult()`.

Check whether `Intent data` is null and whether it `hasExtra()` before using it.

ie,

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(data!=null){
    // Your code
  }
}
```

Comment: could you share an example please?

Comment: it still crashes, please check the updated code above using your advice

Comment: change that logical OR to logical AND inside if condition. Now? Also, what's the need of that `getInfo`? Can't you avoid it?